# "The ) is missing" error

Tags: crystal-reports

I encountered the error "The ) is missing" in Crystal Report when I tried to open a report.

Would greatly appreciate anyone that can help.

Below is the code:

```
// if ( wdaysClass1wdNumWorkDays (date({dss_invdo.dodate}),date({dss_invdo.docdate}) , "12345")-1   ) >1 then "No" else
// if ( wdaysClass1wdNumWorkDays (date({@invdate}),date({@dodate}) , "-23456-")   ) >2 then "No" else
// if ( wdaysClass1wdNumWorkDays (date({@dodate}),date({@invdate}) , "-23456-")   ) >2 then "No" else
// "Yes"


//if {dss_invdo.dodate} <> date('01-jan-1900') then

//( if ( wdaysClass1wdNumWorkDays (date({@dodate}),date({@invdate}) , "12345") -1  ) >1 then "No" else
 if
 ( wdaysClass1wdNumWorkDays (date({@dodate}),date({@invdate}) , "-23456-")   ) >0 and
 ( wdaysClass1wdNumWorkDays (date({@dodate}),date({@invdate}) , "-23456-")   ) <= 2 
 then 
(
 "Yes" 
 )
 else
 (
 "No"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the function `wdaysClass1wdNumWorkDays` comes from an old dll Crystal used to provide. Is that installed?

A better approach might be to look at the example custom functions found in

> C:\Program Files\Crystal Decisions\Crystal Reports 10\Samples\En\Reports\Feature Examples\Custom Functions.rpt

Take a look at the functions under Report Custom Functions in the left hand pane of the formula editor.

Comment: Judah is correct. You're using a custom DLL and it's missing from the machine.